# What is the proper location to store helper methods in Cucumber-Java?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, pageobjects, cucumber-java

I have two methods:

```
public void openEditUserModal() {
   adminUsersPage.admin_user_table_first_user.click();
}
```

and

```
public void waitForUserModal() {
   this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(adminUsersPage.admin_user_modal));
}
```

I initially had these methods as standalone clicks and waits in my step definitions but figured that since they will be reused a lot, it would be good to make helper functions for them.

Is it bad practice to have helper functions in my step definitions file?

Would it be better if I put them in the Page Object file?

Comment: I don't think we have enough code in your question to give you an authoritative answer, but a page object is a great place to put this kind of logic.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put the helper methods would depend on the rest of your project. 
If the helper method is related to a certain page object, that page object would be the best place.

In projects I have worked on, we have also used helper classes related to a certain domain or domain object. (Which is also how I would recommend grouping your step definitions).

You might also be able to extract generic methods that could be reused on multiple page objects.